# How to transfer multiple data from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am trying to get the data from my first table to my another table. I know how to transfer it but I don't want my other columns form my other table have null values. Can you please help me?

`FIRST TABLE`

| IDNUM | STUD_NAME | DATE_TAKEN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BLEH | 11-12-2021 |

`SECOND TABLE`

| IDNUM | STUD_NAME | DATE_TAKEN | ANSWER1 | ANSWER2 | ANSWER1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BLEH | 11-12-2021 | YES | NO | YES |

like this but if tried using the insert and select, the remaining columns will have null values, i don't know what to do T_T

Comment: So what values *do* you want for the additional columns??

Comment: I've removed the majority of tags here. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products; which are you really using. As for Stored Procedures, I don't see anything in the above about them so I'm not sure why they are relevant. You'll need to [edit] your question to (re)add the appropriate tags.

Comment: i want to place the values in table 1 from the second table

Comment: You need to specify what you want Answer1 Answer2 and Answer3 columns to be after the data is inserted. You say you don't want null. If you don't want null, what Do you want in those columns?

Comment: Side note: I personally suggest you normalise your design. There should be 2 columns: Answer Number and Answer Value (not specifically with those names). Having one column per answer breaks basic normalisation rules and doesn't scale. What happens when you need to record 4 answers? 5? 20?

Answer (score 0):

You can include literal values in your insert statement, such as:

```
insert into Table2 (IDNUM, STUD_NAME, DATE_TAKEN, ANSWER1, ANSWER2, ANSWER3)
select IDNUM, STUD_NAME, DATE_TAKEN, 'something', 'something', 'something'
from Table1
```